# Why is object from first iteration deleted on second iteration?

Tags: python, iteration, python-2.x

Given the following code:

```
class wat():
    def __init__(self):
        self.ok = "ok"
        print "hi"

    def __del__(self):
        print "bye"

i = [1,2,3,4]

for thing in i:
    print thing
    hey = wat()
```

I get the following ouput:

```
1
hi
2
hi
bye
3
hi
bye
4
hi
bye
bye
```

It appears that the objects created in one iteration don't get destroyed until **after** the object in the next iteration gets created. Is this what is actually going on, and if so, why does it do that? I was always under the assumption that once the iteration is complete, then all variables and objects die (unless something else is referencing those objects).

Comment: instances of `wat` get destroyed when they are not referenced anymore (= when you assign a new instance to `hey`

Comment: It's worth noting that the Python *language* doesn't guarantee that the `__del__` method is called immediately when the name is re-bound. In the CPython implementation that happens to be true, but not in most other implementations (PyPy, Jython). And even in CPython there are lots of ways to prevent `__del__` from being called in a timely manner or even at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is normal. Each time you run through the `hey = wat()` line, a new object is created (you get the 'hi') and then it replaces the old one that was in `hey`. The old one is then destroyed, because there is nothing referring to it. (note, as explained in the Python documentation for the [Assignment Statements](https://docs.python.org/3.5/reference/simple_stmts.html#assignment-statements), first the right-side expression is evaluated and only then the result is bound to the variable on the left side (hence, you get first a `hi` from the execution of `wat()` and only then `bye`.

Obviously, on the first iteration, `hey` isn't defined, so you got only `hi` after the `1` line.

Comment: then this means i dont understand the scope of variables in for loops. i was thinking that the "hey" variable and whatever it references would get destroyed at the end of each iteration.

Comment: @DanielHosler there is no scope for the loop, variables are still living when it ends.  You can even call `hey` or `thing` after

Comment: No, it does not get destroyed. This is in contrast with other languages that have lexical-scope variables. Python has only global (module-level) and local (function-level, these also exist in anonymous functions such as comprehensions) vars. At the end of a `for` loop, the loop variable will retain the last value assigned to it.

Comment: thanks fellas. i ran a test and i can now see that the object "hey" references will stay alive until "hey" gets reassigned

Answer (score 1):

The un-referenced old object is garbage collected after the creation of the new object, because only after re-using the reference `hey` in the current namespace, the old object is not longer referenced. This happens automatically every loop.

Answer (score 1):

As other community members already explained, `hey` is the only reference to your current instance of `wat`, and once you reassign that reference, the previously referenced object will be garbage collected.

Here is a minor modification to your code that suppresses the garbage collection. It's not really useful apart from being educational.

```
class wat():
    eternal_storage = []

    def __init__(self):
        self.ok = "ok"
        print "hi"
        self.eternal_storage.append(self)

    def __del__(self):
        print "bye"

i = [1,2,3,4]

for thing in i:
    print thing
    hey = wat()
```

Output:

1
hi
2
hi
3
hi
4
hi

Since `wat.eternal_storage` holds all `wat` objects ever created, reassigning the reference `hey` does not remove the last reference to any `wat` object and `wat.__del__` won't be called.